# Mark partition as readonly on flash drive

Tags: windows, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, read-only, removable-media

I have a flash drive that I've encrypted using VeraCrypt. I'd like it to be portable and useable on any computer (pretty much), so I've partitioned it like so:

```
Flash Drive
    - Traveller (Fat32), contains VeraCrypt programs
    - Unencrypted (exFAT), just in case they can't run VeraCrypt
    - Encrypted (VeraCrypt + exFAT), the encrypted data
```

I want to ensure that the traveller partition can't get accidentally overwritten/changed, so I'd like to make it readonly (just the partition, not the disk). I tried using another superuser answer that used diskpart:

```
diskpart
> list vol
> select vol XXX
> att vol set readonly
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
The operation is not supported on removable media.
```

I'm aware that I can set the entire drive to be readonly, but I that stops me from being able to use the rest of it. Are there any ways that work to make just one partition readonly, on a removable flash drive?

Comment: You could perhaps flip the drive between read-only and read-write as needed.

Comment: That's not really feasible, as I'd have to flip it extremely often (I will be writing to the other partitions a lot, as it'll be highly portable). The main reason is that I want that partition to be "relatively readonly" - I'm just protecting it from any accidental writes. i.e. If I ask someone to copy a file onto my drive, I don't want them to accidentally screw anything up on that partition.